# Best Strategy for a guessing game

Tags: probability, game-theory

I have this game theory like problem

Tom and Kathy play a guessing game played in N cities located on a large ring around the earth. Two cities that are adjacent are chosen at random. Tom is sent to one and Kathy the other. Each knows his/her own location and the fact that they are adjacent, but not exact location.

Starting with Tom, they take turns guessing  where the other is. More precisely:

1. A player can choose to name any of the $N$ cities as their guess.
2. Each player hears the other's guess and can use this info to help further decision.
3. A player's guessing strategy can be probabilistic: they can decide to guess city 1 with probability $p_1$, city 2 with $p_2$ and so on.

Whoever guess correct wins.

I need help with the following to questions:

1.If $N=3$, find a strategy for Tom that wins with at least probability $\frac{2}{3}$

2.What are Tom and Kathy's optimal strategy for the general $N$.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do Tom and Kathy know that they are adjacent to one another?

Comment: @NathanH. Yes, they do. I will edit the question to make this clear. Thanks

Comment: I was going to ask why they would guess any city other than one of the two adjacent to them, but then I read your 2nd condition there. They could throw each other off with weird guesses.

Comment: @NathanH. Yep, that's exactly the point.

Comment: I like this problem. Where did you get it?

Comment: I can't get over $\frac 12$ for T...on the first round, his chances can't exceed $\frac 12$ so there has to be at least a $\frac 12$ chance he fails, in which case K can win with probability $\frac 12$ or better.  Which would seem to imply that T has at least a $\frac 14$ chance of losing on the first round...or am I confused?

Comment: @lulu Tom could guess his own city to throw Kathy off.

Comment: @NathanH.   Of course, but that only stands to lower his first round odds.

Comment: @NathanH. Might be a Olympic practice.....

Comment: Does the strategy for Tom that makes him win 2/3 of the time independent of whether or not Kathy knows his strategy?

Comment: Ah, my algebra is correct but my conclusion is wrong.  My argument shows (correctly, I think) that T can't have a $\frac 34$ strategy.  But of course, $\frac 23< \frac 34$.

Comment: Do not answer this problem. It is from the Mathcamp qualifying quiz here: https://mathcamp.org/prospectiveapplicants/quiz/index.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is from a live contest.

Comment: Flag the question (or @-ping me) when the contest is over. Or, at least communicate the deadline date somehow to the diamond moderators :-)

Answer (score 3):

Do not answer this problem, it is from the Mathcamp qualifying quiz here: https://mathcamp.org/prospectiveapplicants/quiz/index.php